# Loop through JSON ARRAY and get value with node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, parsing

I have http request in json string and I need response to..
I need to get value from the string as I be able to return response
exactly I need value of
queryResult->outputContexts->name  1st(item).
The json string is as follow:

```
{
    "responseId": "61e3f7da-b529-49e0-80-9eaae4695ec1-ee7586fb",
    "queryResult": {
        "queryText": "Get My VIP Card",
        "parameters": {
            "PARAM": ""
        },
        "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
        "outputContexts": [
            {
                "name": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/sessions/v-2-404581/contexts/fulllllll-followup",
                "lifespanCount": 1,
                "parameters": {
                    "PARAM": "",
                    "PARAM.original": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/sessions/v-2-4024581/contexts/__system_counters__",
                "lifespanCount": 1,
                "parameters": {
                    "no-input": 0,
                    "no-match": 0,
                    "PARAM": "",
                    "PARAM.original": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "intent": {
            "name": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/intents/74a9a-335b-46ea-817a-2cb45fcc04a5",
            "displayName": "fulllllll"
        },
        "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
        "languageCode": "en"
    },
    "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
        "payload": {
            "source": "viber",
            "body": {
                "timestamp": 1604958504809,
                "event": "message",
                "silent": false,
                "sender": {
                    "api_version": 8,
                    "name": "john smith",
                    "country": "MK",
                    "language": "en-US",
                    "id": "as6q0NaBQjKiTPDw=="
                },
                "message": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Get My VIP Card"
                },
                "chat_hostname": "SN-CHAT-10_",
                "message_token": 5506704778261146000
            },
            "contact": {
                "cId": "as6q0NQQ+IdadsajKiTPDw=="
            }
        }
    },
    "session": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/sessions/v-2-424581"
}
```

As I was reading around, I should loop through objects in string array but I could not find similar sample, as the objects are different inside..
I need some basic insrtuction how to loop through json array in node.js
thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe try something like: queryResult.outputContexts.map(obj => {return {name: obj.name}}).

I'm not sure if this is what you want tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mean time I found a very easy way to get value from json array as follow:

Important NOTE (especially for the beginners):

If you are receiving response with http request, response is coming as a text string, so you need first to convert to JSON object as be abblle to extract values from array.

Full sample of the response is written on beginig of this thread.

```
http request code 
...
res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    const response = JSON.parse(body.toString()); //convert string to JSON object

    var result = response.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.contact.cId;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
 });
```

OR:

```
...
    var result = response.queryResult.outputContexts[0].name;
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform what you want you would like to take a look at [Array documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) as queryResult->outputContexts is an array. Also, to understand some parts of the solution I'm posting, about [Destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const response = {
    "responseId": "61e3f7da-b529-49e0-80-9eaae4695ec1-ee7586fb",
    "queryResult": {
        "queryText": "Get My VIP Card",
        "parameters": {
            "PARAM": ""
        },
        "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
        "outputContexts": [
            {
                "name": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/sessions/v-2-404581/contexts/fulllllll-followup",
                "lifespanCount": 1,
                "parameters": {
                    "PARAM": "",
                    "PARAM.original": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/sessions/v-2-4024581/contexts/__system_counters__",
                "lifespanCount": 1,
                "parameters": {
                    "no-input": 0,
                    "no-match": 0,
                    "PARAM": "",
                    "PARAM.original": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "intent": {
            "name": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/intents/74a9a-335b-46ea-817a-2cb45fcc04a5",
            "displayName": "fulllllll"
        },
        "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
        "languageCode": "en"
    },
    "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
        "payload": {
            "source": "viber",
            "body": {
                "timestamp": 1604958504809,
                "event": "message",
                "silent": false,
                "sender": {
                    "api_version": 8,
                    "name": "john smith",
                    "country": "MK",
                    "language": "en-US",
                    "id": "as6q0NaBQjKiTPDw=="
                },
                "message": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Get My VIP Card"
                },
                "chat_hostname": "SN-CHAT-10_",
                "message_token": 5506704778261146000
            },
            "contact": {
                "cId": "as6q0NQQ+IdadsajKiTPDw=="
            }
        }
    },
    "session": "projects/mbmsoft-nehh/agent/sessions/v-2-424581"
};

const { queryResult } = response;
const { outputContexts } = queryResult;

outputContexts.forEach(({ name }) => {
    
    console.log(name);
    
});

const nameArray = outputContexts.map(({ name }) => {
    
    return name;
    
});

console.log(nameArray);
```

In the answer, there are 2 solutions:

1. Using **foreach** you can iterate over the array and perform an operation with each name value.
2. Using **map** you can create an array with all the name values and use it ash you wish.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

1.I follow instruction from @Nicolas Mauricio, I moved forward as follow:

```
exports.id_session = function () {
    const { queryResult } = response;
    const { outputContexts } = queryResult;
    const nameArray = outputContexts.map(({ name }) => {
        return name;
    });
    console.log(nameArray)
    let a, b, rest;
    [a, ...rest] = nameArray;
    console.log(a);
    return a; 
};
```

As I'm very new in node.js I will thanks to anyone if can send some another way to extract value from json array.